# Teradata setLoginTimeout not working

Tags: jdbc, timeout, teradata

I am building an app in extjs connecting to teradata at the back-end.  It works fine locally but when deployed its giving

> [Error 1277] [SQLState 08S01] Login time-out for Connection to server after 12seconds.

I am trying to increase the timeout now.

```
Class.forName("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver");
DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(100);
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, "user", "pass");
```

Still I'm getting same time-out error after 12 seconds. It seems like setLoginTimeout didn't work. Where am I going wrong? Is there any other solution other than increasing time-out ?

P.S: For one server it worked fine now I changed only the server name to point to another server and I'm getting timeout.

Comment: The driver potentially ignores the logintimeout set on DriverManager; check with the vendor, or maybe there is a serverside timeout as well.

Comment: Thank you Mark. Is there any other way to control the timeout value. Its working fine locally. Only in server I get this problem. Should It be because of timeout value or do you see any other problem ?

Comment: That depends on the JDBC driver and/or the server. Check its documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below link might help you.

http://forums.teradata.com/forum/connectivity/could-you-tell-me-the-reason-why-login-time-out